# Foundation's string encoding isn't what sites are expecting

Tags: swift, url, networking, encoding, foundation

Specifically, it's encoding characters with an umlaut as two characters.

```
let unencoded = "könnten"
let encoded = unencoded.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
```

`encoded` is then equal to `ko%CC%88nnten`.  So, it's converting the `ö` into `o%CC%88`. So it's really like `o¨`, where the umlaut (`¨`) and the `o` are separate.

However, most sites seem to be expecting the encoding to be `%C3%B6`, which is `ö`, where the umlaut (`¨`) and `o` are one single character.

You can see an example of the encoding not working here (how `Foundation` wants to encode it):

https://www.linguee.com/german-english/search?query=ko%CC%88nnten

And how it would ideally be:

https://www.linguee.com/german-english/search?query=k%C3%B6nnten

Is there a better way to be encoding this?  Maybe different options or a different framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, the server should cope with both precomposed and decomposed
strings. But if necessary, you can precompose the string on the
client side:

```
let unencoded = "könnten"
let encoded = unencoded.precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping
        .stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!

print(encoded) // k%C3%B6nnten
```

See [Technical Q&A QA1235 – Converting to Precomposed Unicode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1235/_index.html)
for more information.

Comment: Awesome, it works perfectly.  Thanks for the explanation.  Yea, it would be great if the sites I'm using would accept both formats, but alas :/ It seems to be pretty common that they don't.